# How do range queries work in Python's kd-tree?

Tags: python, range, kdtree

What is a range query over a kdtree and how is it done by python?

Comment: There's no built-in kD tree in Python -- in fact, there's no tree support at all. What are you using to implement this tree?

Comment: @katrielalex, I'm assuming he means the one in scipy.spatial. Although there are obviously others, the most obvious being http://code.google.com/p/python-kdtree/.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about [the k-d tree in scipy.spatial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html), there are a couple of range queries. Which is to say, there are multiple functions that take as their input one or more points and a radius and query the tree for all points within the radius of the query points.

The two most obvious functions are `query_ball_point` and `query_ball_tree`.

You can read the source code [on github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/spatial/kdtree.py) to see how these queries are implemented.

Comment: Though I could be mistaken, I believe a range query usually refers to sampling within a k-dimensional hypercube (i.e., you restrict the first coordinate to the range [a,b], the second coordinate to the range [c,d], ..., the last coordinate to the range [y,z].)